# How to route static files and a different application in NGINX?

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, nginx, next.js

I want to serve static files on my Nginx server for my "/" route and also serve files from a NextJS server/upstream for all the other routes.

If i turn off the NextJS server (which runs in development mode for now) I can see my static page on "/", but when I go back and just turn on the server again, the NextJS server takes care of everything again...

I'm completely new with Nginx, so any help would be appreciated!

```
upstream nextjs_node {
    ip_hash;
    server remora_nextjs_1:3000;
}
...
location = / {
  proxy_set_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
...
location / {
  proxy_set_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;

  proxy_pass http://nextjs_node;
}
```

The idea is to server only static files for the initial route and for all the others run a node application (NextJS)

Comment: First you can set the root in nginx server block and use `try_files` and then you should create a location context. So Nginx will first try to serve your static file first and then pass it to nextjs node app.